# Template deduction syntactical differences

Tags: c++, templates

I wrote a basic program for binary trees as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
using sp = std::unique_ptr<T>;

template<typename T>
struct Node{
    Node(T val):
      x(val){
    }

    const sp<Node>& addL(T val){
        left = std::make_unique<Node>(val);
        return left;
    }

    const sp<Node>& addR(T val){
        right = std::make_unique<Node>(val);
        return right;
    }

    private:
    T x;
    sp<Node> left;
    sp<Node> right;
};

int main(){
    auto root = std::make_unique<Node<int>>(5);
    root->addL(10)->addR(4)->addL(12);
    root->addR(14)->addL(3)->addR(15);
}
```

My question was regarding this line

```
auto root = std::make_unique<Node<int>>(5);
```

If I remove the `<int>` template parameter then the compiler complains of template deduction failure

```
tree.cpp:44:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘make_unique<template<class T> struct Node>(int)’
   44 |     auto root = std::make_unique<Node>(5);
      |                                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/memory:80,
                 from tree.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:848:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Tp, class ... _Args> typename std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object std::make_unique(_Args&& ...)’
  848 |     make_unique(_Args&&... __args)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:848:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

whereas a similar deduction works in the line

```
left = std::make_unique<Node>(val);
```

Is this because the code within the struct, when being compiled already has the template deduced and thus the explicit specification of `<int>` isn't required? Does that also explain why `sp<Node<T>>` isn't required in the signature of the class functions and `sp<Node>` is adequate for the compiler to infer the actual type.

P.S. `g++ (Ubuntu 9.2.1-17ubuntu1~16.04) 9.2.1 20191102`

Comment: It is called injected class template names. Every occurence of `Node` inside method of your class template is translated into `Node<T>`. So you don't have to put T explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [injected-class-name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name),
in the scope of the class `Node<T>`, `Node` also refers to `Node<T>`.

So, in

```
left = std::make_unique<Node>(val); // Inside class scope
```

There are no deductions, but just the injected class name, so equivalent to

```
left = std::make_unique<Node<T>>(val); // Inside class scope
```

Outside of class scope, `Node` refer to template class.

So

```
auto root = std::make_unique<Node>(5); // Invalid
```

As template parameter of `make_unique` is type and not a template template parameter.

So you have to write:

```
auto root = std::make_unique<Node<int>>(5);
```